# On a J-1 visa, and wish to apply for ESTA to travel to Mexico during grace period

Tags: visas, esta, greece

I am on a J-1 Visa as a Greek citizen until end of April 2018, and have already got my tickets to Mexico for the 2nd of May, returning on the 19th to NYC , where my plane for Amsterdam  departs on the 25th of May (Amsterdam is our current home vs our permanent home in Athens).

I with to apply for an ESTA as a group for both myself and my daughter, who is now on s J-2 visa. If I pay it today, when does the ESTA period starts, as we are already in NYC. On the ESTA application I have indicated for our address our current place in Brooklyn, or should I note the address in Amsterdam?

Answer (score 1):

While each of you would apply for your own independent ESTA, you are able to [group the applications](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/application.html;jsessionid=3JEpzk4vdiO5hnBE0sjyZpD0M3mNPNqTwSaeWjjhMXg2FBZO82pY!1596070274?execution=e1s1) and make one payment.

It may take only moments to be notified that the applications have been accepted, although it can take longer, up to 72 hours. Your ESTA validity starts on the date you are approved, and is generally valid for two years (multiple entry) or until your passport expires, whichever comes first.

As you are in the country (and USCIS is aware of that), it makes sense to put your US contact information.